# tfs: delete files on the repository server and leave them locally

Tags: tfs

I have accidentally checked in some files that I meant keeping locally on my machine.
How do I delete them from the repository but leave a local copy of them in my solution ?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the obvious brute-force solution of copying the files to a temporary location, fixing source control, then adding them back in to your project.

Comment: I thought that there is something safer. Thanks anyway