# How to delete file from TFS and exclude from source control?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a project where I'm writing a library. I have a file, lets call it... tester.cs which I use for testing the library. Now, I'm only supposed to check in the library but i accidentally also checked in tester.cs. Is there any way I can delete it from the remote server without deleting it locally? and also ultimately removing it from source control? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a file from TFS repository without deleting local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063177/how-to-delete-a-file-from-tfs-repository-without-deleting-local-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to delete files on the TFS server and leave them locally. There's the obvious **brute-force solution of copying the files to a temporary location**, fixing source control, then adding them back in to your project.

And also here is a similar question for your reference: [How to delete a file from TFS repository without deleting local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063177/how-to-delete-a-file-from-tfs-repository-without-deleting-local-file)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's as simple as making a local copy of a file, deleting it in TFS and moving the local copy back to the original location. Visual Studio does not allow you to do that in a C# project or Source Control Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends really on what you mean by 'delete'. TFVC has the concept of delete which flags a file as deleted in the Project Collection database (and removes it from your workspace etc.). And you have the concept op '[destroy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control)' which means the file will be removed from the Project Collection databases, and action that is unrecoverable except by restoring a backup of TFS. But this will leave your local file in place and erase all traces of the file in source control.

However, if you added it to your project in VS (.proj file) then there will be a reference to the file in there as well for compilation etc. This **will** cause issues when other users perform a Get-Latest of your solution.

Also if you are using a local workspace you can use .tfignore files to prevent such files from being added into the local workspace in the first place. See [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server), near the bottom there is some information about the .tfignore file and how they work.